# Bulma css: Fixed navbar still move a little bit

Tags: navbar, bulma

First: I am sorry about my english

here is my problem
when the page was opened
fixed navbar is still work properly
[image]

after the user scrolls down, the navbar will move up and left haft of it.
[image]

In the navbar class I added "is-fixed-top" and in the body class I added "has-navbar-fixed-top"

Beginner
Thanks

Comment: Please specify your specific question and show any work you have done.

Comment: Hey! Do you have examples of your code? That would be more helpful for us to know what is going wrong!